# Is every real vector bundle immersed in the tangent bundle of a Manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

- For me "manifold" = "$C^\infty$-manifold" and also "vector bundle" = "smooth vector bundle"

There's not much context, im learning about Vector Bundles and I wonder if every vector bundle over a manifold can be inmerse in the tangent bundle of a Manifold. Even stronger, let $E$ be a vector bundle over a manifold $M$ with fibers of dimension equal to $dim (M)$, I would like to know if there is a diffeomorphism $f:M \rightarrow M$ whose push-out $f_* :E \rightarrow T(M)$ is a vector bundle isomorphism. If the answer to the last one is negative, are there some hypothesis over $M$ and/or $E$ to make it true? For example, I've just realised you can take many different vector bundles over $S^1$ not ishomorphic (because they make a different amount of Twists).

Comment: Notice that the tangent space $TQ$ of a manifold $Q$ always has even dimension (2 times $Q$'s dimension), while there are vector bundles of odd dimension (for example the trivial bundle $Q\times\mathbb R\rightarrow Q$)

Comment: You are right, Naive mistake, let me change the question a little bit

Comment: Im starting to feel like there is a trivial answer to my first question, but Im learning so I dont see it

Comment: The tangent bundle of the circle $S^1$ is trivial. But there are $1$-dimensional bundles over $S^1$ (e.g., the Möbius strip) that are not trivial.(P.S., I don't think you are using the term "push-out" in its correct sense.)

Comment: Yes, thats what I've just realiced, sorry for changing the question. May be the vector bundles over $S^1$ modulo isomorphism are parameterized by the number of twist?

Comment: ... number of twists mod $2$. ;)

Comment: May be I should delete the question and ask again when I have things more clear

Comment: What is the "push out" $f_*: E\to TM$? The one I know is $f_*: TM\to TM$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throughout, let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold.

It will not generally be the case that every rank $n$ vector bundle over $M$ is isomorphic to $TM$. For instance, whenever there is more than one isomorphism class of rank $n$ vector bundle over $M$ there will be counterexamples, since at most one of them contains $TM$. Thus, for any nontrivial bundle $E\to M$, either $E$ or $M\times\mathbb{R}^n$ is not isomorphic to $TM$. For instance, we have the counterexamples

- The Möbius strip $\Sigma\to S^1$
- The trivial bundle over the sphere $S^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\to S^2$.
- The "twisted" bundle over the torus $\Sigma\times S^1\times\mathbb{R}\to S^1\times S^1$ (where $\Sigma$ still denotes the Möbius strip)

and so on. It might be worth noting that whenever $M$ is contractible, all vector bundles over $M$ *are* isomorphic (and thus isomorphic to $TM$).

The question of what distinguishes $TM$ among rank $n$ vector bundles over $M$ is a bit more subtle. One can define a *tangent structure* to be a $(1,1)$-tensor field $J$ on the total space $E$ of a vector bundle $E\to M$ satisfying certain axioms. The tangent structure exists for all tangent bundles, and the existence of such a tensor field on an arbitrary vector bundle $E$ ensures that $E$ is isomorphic to $TM$. [This wikipedia subsection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_tangent_bundle#Canonical_tensor_fields_on_the_tangent_bundle) gives a brief overview of the definition of this tensor field.

Comment: Thanks, what distinguishes $TM$ among rank n vector bundles over $M$ is exactly what I was trying to ask but couldn't find the words.