# What properties define the tangent bundle up to diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces, tangent-bundle

In the theory of smooth manifolds there are *many* ways in which the tangent bundle can be defined, begging the question: **what set of properties define the tangent bundle 'up to diffeomorphism'?**

These properties would be such that, given a manifold $M$,

1. $TM$, whether defined by derivations or tangent curves or something else, complies with these properties.
2. Any two manifolds complying with such properties are diffeomorphic.
3. The theory of the tangent bundle can be develop from these properties alone

---

As an example, the following properties define $\mathbb{R}$ up to isomorphism:

- $\mathbb{R}$ is an ordered field.
- $\mathbb{R}$ has the least upper bound property.

These properties are such that

1. $\mathbb{R}$, whether defined by Dedekind Cuts or Cauchy sequences, complies with these properties.
2. Any sets complying with such properties are isomorphic.
3. The theory of $\mathbb{R}$ can be develop from these properties alone.

---

**Edit:** I've been considering the following:

**Result (?):** Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $m$, then there is a unique manifold $N$ up to diffeomorphism such that:

1. $\dim N = 2m$.
2. There is a smooth submersion $N\hookrightarrow M$.
3. Any $p\in N$ belongs to a chart $(U,\phi)$ where $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism $U\to M\times \mathbb{R}^m$.
4. ...

At least a fourth condition is needed, perhaps one that would keep the 'size' of $N$ in check, as $M\times \mathbb{R}^m$ (too 'small') complies with the first three conditions.

Comment: May I know why the post was downvoted? I'm willing to edit it if necessary (:

Comment: I did not downvote your post but I find it rather unclear. First of all, the title does not match the body. More importantly, it is unclear if $M$ is given in advance. Thirdly, are you asking for a characterization of the tangent bundle among vector bundles with the given base manifold? I stop here.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you. Regarding your first point, I rewrote the post in hopes of making it more clear; let me know if something else needs clarification. Regarding your second point: yes, the manifold $M$ is given. Finally, I don't recall reading (so far) about vector bundles in Lee's _Intro to Smooth Manifolds_, so knowing very little about vector bundles I struggle to understand your last question, could you perhaps elaborate/rephrase it?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think that's too pedantic. Obviously $M$ needs to be given for the question to make sense, and seeing this can be expected of anyone knowledgeable enough to answer the question. And the last part about characterization among which objects is asked for: What's so bad about leaving that open? If someone has a characterization among vector bundles over $M$, let them give that characterization, and if someone has a characterization among manifolds, let them give that characterization.

Comment: There is no way I can explain in comments what a vector bundle is. Check the Wikipedia article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle

Comment: Isn't there something called an almost-tangent structure? Like an almost-complex structure, but with $J^2=0$ instead of $J^2=-1$. Tangent bundles have canonical almost-tangent structures. If memory serves right, there's a type of Nijenhuis tensor for almost-tangent structures, which vanishes if and only if the manifold is locally equivalent to a tangent bundle with its canonical structure.

Comment: For a characterization of tangent bundles among vector bundles, see the answer to  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4097364/is-every-real-vector-bundle-immersed-in-the-tangent-bundle-of-a-manifold

Comment: Late to the party, but one issue with the question is the phrase "up to diffeomorphism," which might better be replaced by "up to isomorphism of real vector bundles (a Very Particular type of diffeomorphism between Very Particular manifolds)."

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a reasonable one, but I don't see any easy answer. Your example is a rather simple object with, as you say, only two properties that uniquely define it. Note, however, that the properties have to be stated in terms of mathematical terms (ordered, field, least upper bound) that have to be defined.

More complex mathematical objects such as a manifold or its tangent bundle require a longer and more complex list of properties. In particular, a crucial aspect of manifolds and their tangent bundles are their so-called local properties. Locality is a powerful concept that pervades almost every area of mathematics including even algebra. But it makes the definitions more involved.

If you assume you know what smooth functions defined on a neighborhood of $p \in M$ are, then the definition of $T_pM$ as the space of derivations on smooth functions defined in a neighborhood of $p$ is essentially a definition using properties only. It just relies on more terminology and the definitions of the terms used. But the spirit is the same.

There's another way to proceed. The idea is to associate to each point $p \in M$ a vector space. The cotangent space at $p$ can be defined to be
$$ T^*_pM = \mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I^2}, $$
where $f \in \mathcal{I}$ if it is a smooth function whose domain is a open neighborhood of $p$ and that vanishes at $p$. And $\mathcal{I}$ is the ideal generated by squares of functions in $\mathcal{I}$.
$T^*_pM$ is obviously a vector space. The tangent space at $p$ is the dual vector space
$$ T_pM = (T_p^*M)^*. $$

All of the better known properties of $T_*M$ can be derived from this definition. But this is overly complicated, which is why we never use it. It's used in algebraic geometry, because the spaces there are not as simply defined.